# Documentation on Kentico 'Atom Data Source' web part?

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to use the 'Atom Data Source' web part in conjunction with a basic repeater, but am having no luck.  I'm using a valid atom feed from the AP in my data source.  I always get 'no data found'.  My ascx transformation is simply trying to display the title node:

It's possible i'm not properly referencing items in the feed, but I've had trouble locating any documentation on the 'Atom Data Source' web part.

Has anyone else had luck using this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use RSS Repeater instead of Basic one. You can find examples in documentation [here](https://docs.kentico.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12649277) and [there](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Usage+example+-+External+RSS+feed).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Unfortunately the RSS repeater is used to _generate_ an RSS feed, not use another data source to render content.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup of an Atom Data Source and a Basic Repeater will work.  Make sure of a few things:

- You have a valid Atom source link or data
- You have taken the ID from the Atom data source and placed it in the Basic Repeater datasource property.  It has to match exactly.
- If you have an XSD, use that in your datasource.

I just tested in v9 with this atom link and was able to return all the posts without issue using your setup.  http://blog.case.edu/news/feed.atom

Comment: Thanks for verifying that I'm shooting in the right direction.  I tried using the feed you mentioned, and cant get it to return any data.  I'm using an ASCX transformation that contains only this macro:  

<%# Eval("title") %>

Which just returns empty sets of data.    Am I missing something obvious?

I'm running Kentico 8.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The Associated Press Atom feed gave us the same headache five years ago (see this old [Devnet thread](http://devnet.kentico.com/forums?forumid=45&threadid=23573)). Brendan is right on target about the setup on the Kentico side, but unfortunately, there's something janky on the AP side.

Theoretically your approach with the data source should work as Brendan pointed out, but when we tried setting it up for AP, the feed would turn up empty. The workaround we settled on for a time was using Yahoo! Pipes to read the AP Atom feed, convert it to RSS and then pull the converted feed into Kentico. Not pretty. Plus, Yahoo drained the Pipes project last August. :(

That said, here are a few options to consider--

- Custom code to rewrite AP's Atom feed.
- Hit AP's API directly. Check out the AP [dev site](https://developer.ap.org/ap-content-api) and
  [GitHub](https://github.com/TheAssociatedPress/APISamples).
- Tinker with the XSD. Maybe a generic one would work? Or download AP's
  and serve it from your own domain, perhaps a modified version?
- Set up AP Custom News json. See the [AP Hosted](http://hosted2admin.ap.org/) site.

We choose the third option, and it has worked out well. One main advantage is that you can build as many custom feeds as you want and target the stories that matter most to your readers. You'll have to check with your AP bureau to set up an account if you don't already have one.

Each feed starts with a search you build that hits AP's entire wire and targets the categories and terms you set, say for instance, business+liverpool+manufacturing or sports+cycling+italy.

Then in Kentico add a call to the AP js -- `<script src="http://hosted2.ap.org/scripts/CustomNews.js"></script>` -- and then for the json place a div on the appropriate page -- `<div id="[your publication's Associated Press ID and GUID]" class="ap-json"></div>`

AP Custom News has info on building searches and modules [here](http://hosted2admin.ap.org/help/index.htm).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great information!  I actually have a call schedule with someone from AP tomorrow to talk options, i'll ask them about the JSON route.  I might give XSD another shot too, although I tried a few things, none of which seemed to work out.  I'll update the thread should I have any luck.  Thanks again!